# Access output from java compiler in C#

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, standards

I'm writing a program in C# that will compile java files using the java compiler (javac). I am having trouble capturing the output from javac (a command-line tool) to tell the user of errors. I know how to start a process and capture the standard output, but javac returns nothing. Is there any other way that I can capture the output, or better yet, get a list of errors from java compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you better use error output of the process. `Process.StandardError`

Comment: Thank you... I had StandardError set up, but I forgot to redirect the standard error.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because errors are being sent to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. One way you can get around this is to redirect output to `stderr` to `stdout` and capture that. eg:

```
javac files.java 2>&1
```

Or you can also access the [`Process.StandardError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) stream as MAKKAM suggested.