# How to compile Java from C#?

Tags: c#, java

I'm trying to use the following C# code to compile Java using javac:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "javac";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + @"/TempJava");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-d "Application.StartupPath + @"/TempJava" + files;
p.Start();
```

"files" represents a string variable containing the name(s) of the `*.java` files.

All in all, I want to create a new folder, and then take the Java files (from where ever they may be located) and compile it into a class file(s) in TempJava.

For some reason, the code doesn't work, no errors, no warnings, but when I run it and check TempJava, there's no files in it.

Comment: What do your environment variables look like?  Are they (especially the one pointing to the java compiler) correct?

Comment: Yes, because I can run javac by entering it manually on the command prompt, and it works fine.

Comment: Also, are you on Unix? The slashes imply so, so there's no reason to make it a raw string, even though it's a path.

Comment: Try printing the standard output and error of the process, and its exit code. See what you find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access output from java compiler in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775482/access-output-from-java-compiler-in-c)

Comment: So you might want a backslash. Even better, use System.IO.Path.Combine.

Comment: From the duplicate question use Process.StandardError

Answer (score 2):

Just because your child process ends with a possible error, it doesn't mean your parent process must be aware of it.

Inspect the process' exit code and standard output stream, and especially the standard error stream. Your answer lies in there...

Comment: Well if you going to provide an answer you might as well include the link to [Process.StandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx)

Comment: Duly noted. Your comment is the first one, so it is quite visible, so for now I'll leave it at that.

Comment: How exactly should I read the standard error stream, and what are things I should be looking for?

Comment: Let's say you're debugging, then in the Immediate Window create a new StreamReader and pass it the StandardError property of the process, *after* you've started it and waited for it to finish (using the WaitForExit method). Then read the whole stream (.ReadToEnd) and look at the output. You can also check the process' exit code which would be 0 for success, and anything else otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, you've been incredibly helpful, however when I do that, it gives me an overloaded method error.

Answer (score 0):

here i have 2 buttons run and compile here is some code to help.

```
private void comp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = "javac " + label1.Text + file + "@pause" + "@stop";
        text = text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);

        File.WriteAllText(label1.Text + "Compile.bat", text);

        Process proc = null;
        try
        {
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = label1.Text + "Compile.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }

    private void runp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string news = file.Remove(file.Length - 5);
        string text = "java " + news + "@pause";
        text = text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);

        File.WriteAllText(label1.Text + "Run.bat", text);

        Process proc = null;
        try
        {
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = label1.Text + "Run.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = label1.Text.Remove(label1.Text.Length - 1);
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

all i really do is create a batch and run it using c#.